# what's wrong with my steps,why there is no output?

Tags: php, magento

I'm using Magento, and want to echo 'welcome, my visitor!' on the right part of the default template.  I've performed the following steps, but there's no output.

First, in `page.xml`

```
 <block type="core/text_list" name="right" as="right" translate="label">
                <label>Right Column</label>
                <block type="catalog/navigation" name="category.listing" template="catalog/navigation/categories.phtml" />
            </block>
```

I add

```
<block type="catalog/navigation" name="category.listing" template="catalog/navigation/categories.phtml" />`
```

Second, I created the file `template/catalog/navigation/categories.phtml` containing the following code in it.

```
   <?php echo 'welcome, my visitor!'; ?>
```

After doing this, there's no output? How can I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: what is the error ? and which quotes you use ? **`** or **'** ?

Comment: there is no welcome, my visitor! output? i only do it for test

Comment: What templating library are you using?

Comment: the template is created by myself. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You're using back-ticks instead of single- or double-quotes.

It should be:

`<?php echo 'welcome, my visitor!'; ?>`

Back-ticks are used to execute shell commands: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php

Comment: I'm not very familiar with XML but does `template="catalog/navigation/categories.phtml"` need to be `template="template/catalog/navigation/categories.phtml"`? (based on your file location).